# Removing the font toolbar in a new message

Tags: macos, mail.app, preferences

In the Mac (mountain lion) mail.app (v 6.2), when composing a new message, I'm looking to hide the default font/styling bar that appears beneath the standard toolbar at the top of the window.

I've checked the view menu and found nothing and have also tried to customized the toolbar to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First go to View > Show Toolbar. Then, click this button:

[image]

That's all there is to it!

Comment: Guess I hid the main toolbar before I could even see that it was that simple. I almost feel challenged having asked this. Thank you for your help! Forest for the trees…